# How does installing XCode, Visual Studio and Unity on my mac impact my computer's speed?

Tags: macos, xcode, performance, sound-volume

Most of the time I use my mac computer for graphics design but I enjoy coding too. Since clean-installing macOS a few months ago, I avoided installing XCode, Unity and Visual Studio for fear that with all their dependencies, they might *bog down* my aging computer.

However I wonder whether this is the actual case given that osx apps *tend to be* statically linked and self-contained.

Do these three Dev Tools slow my computer down somehow by their mere existence, or is it only disk space that they occupy when I am not using them?

Answer (score 2):

No, they do not slow your computer down by their mere existence. Yes, they will occupy disk space.

It hasn't got anything to do with them being statically linked.

Comment: You could run I'd run etrecheck on the server. The proprietary stuff gets filtered.

-- Download etrecheck.  Click on the download link at the bottom of the screen.
http://etrecheck.com/

-- Run etrecheck.   The first five runs are free.

-- Using EtreCheck by etresoft, the author
https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-11591  before and after and see if any backgrounds apps were running.

Comment: that was a good point @historystamp! unfortunately I already installed all these tools last evening so I can no longer compare it to the "before" state...

Comment: Etrecheck does a good job of identifying all started processes.  I think you should be able to identify the odd processes by their name. I'd run it after.

Comment: Once again thank you! - Etrecheck came up clean - I additionally checked for new kexts, the System Preferences > Login items, LaunchDaemons and LaunchAgents (at /System/Library/, ~/Library/ and /Library/) but couldn't find anything newly installed.

Answer (score 0):

It won't slow your Mac unless your using it, it does occupy the space. But incase you run all the 3 programs mentioned simultaneously then there will be a affect in the speed.

Let's get straight to the point
Speed depends on the ram or the primary memory (in general) therefore just by installing and not turning it on won't consume and ram, but yes there will be a small impact in speed when you run them.